# How do I create a really long table in a two column layout?

Tags: tables, two-column, longtable

I have a table that has about 130 rows. I tried using the `longtable` package, but it does not work with two column documents. The table will be starting near the top of the left column, and it should continue on to the right column, and perhaps continue onto the next page as well. Is there are way to get this to work reasonably well in two column documents?

**EDIT:** The table has 3 columns, and it is narrow enough to fit on one column of a standard two column layout.

Comment: From a design perspective, isn't this a really bad idea?

Comment: Well, I kind of need it for completeness sake. I am only putting it in the appendix of my thesis.

Comment: @Seamus: What's the problem?  If the table is narrow and space is at a premium, then I can see why one would want to do this.

Comment: @donatello: interesting question - how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

It depends a bit on the content of the table. If it has only two columns, I would use a list. If each entry is only on one row, you could use tabbing. If there are columns of type "p" you could replace the table by lines with \parboxes (The package eqparbox can help to synchronize their sizes). If you need headers and footers you could look at supertabular.

Comment: The table has 3 columns. Please see the edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`supertabular` [can be made to work with `multicols`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14819/5763). So I suggest you use `supertabular` instead of `longtable`. Or [use a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13895/5763).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by hand using `\vsplit`.  Set the table in a really long vbox, and break up the table one column at a time.