# multicolumn long table or enumeration

Tags: tables, lists, page-breaking, enumerate, multicol

I would like to generate a multi-column table that wraps within columns of the document, and splits across pages.  There are a couple of similar questions here

[How do I create a really long table in a two column layout?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6400/how-do-i-create-a-really-long-table-in-a-two-column-layout)

[Two-column longtable or tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/two-column-longtable-or-tabular)

But neither seem really to resolve the problem.

Criteria:

The table/list will be generated with a loop, with an arbitrary number of rows.
It should split over pages.
It should be usable in a multicols environment.

The closest solution seems to be to use a list instead of a table, but this has the problem of lining up the top rows when the list is wrapped in a multicols environment.  Below is a sample document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen,enumitem}
\def\stnum{30} % number of items
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}p{.5in}}

\setlist{nolistsep}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries\arabic*.\qquad},leftmargin=1.3in]
\item[Item \#]
\whiledo{\value{enumi}<\stnum}{
\item \begin{tabular}{CC}T & F\end{tabular}
\item[]{\color{black!20}\rule{1.5in}{3ex}}
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

The main problem is how to line up the rows properly (as if this were a table.) A secondary problem would be to have the equivalent of a repeated column header when the columns wrap.

Here's a partial picture of the output of the document above:

[image: output of code]

Comment: I don't understand what "line up the rows properly " means, or how your example fails to do so.

Comment: If this were a table, then the 19 (the top of the second column) would line up with the 1 (the top of the first column.) If I take out the "Item #" line, that will happen for the first page of the example, but is not guranteed to happen in subsequent pages.  Is that clearer?

Comment: "Is not guaranteed" -- do you mean that a new multicol column could start with a grey-colored rule?

Comment: @lockstep Yes, exactly. But that just gave me an idea for a solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's possible to trick `supertabular` to work inside a `multicols` environment by redefining `\newpage` to be `\columnbreak` in the first column and `\newpage` in the second. I also needed to stick a height 0, width `\linewidth` rule at the bottom of the first column. Strange things happen without it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,supertabular,multicol}
\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<300
        \advance\n by1
        \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                \textbf{\number\n.}&
                \hfill T\hfill\hfill F\hfill\hskip0pt\endgraf
                \vskip.5\baselineskip
                \color@begingroup
                \color{black!20}
                \hrule height3ex
                \color@endgroup
                \tabularnewline
        }
\repeat
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\newpage{%
        \if@firstcolumn
                \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
                \columnbreak
        \else
                \mcnewpage
        \fi
}
\makeatother
\tablehead{Item \#&\\}
\begin{supertabular}{lp{1.5in}}
\tablebody
\end{supertabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

I'm not actually sure that this is the best way to generate the body, but it works.
[image]

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks. Deciding on who gets the bounty is going to be tough!

Comment: Playing around with this, it seems that the table is shorter than it needs to be (by about 2 rows) This can be fixed by adding `\shrinkheight{-.3em}` to the table body command.

Comment: I've decided to accept this answer over lockstep's because it works using a tabular environment, which allows for more flexibility in formatting columns, and also allows a repeatable header row.  Thanks for a great solution!

Comment: @Alan: No problem. This is actually not the first time I've hacked on `supertabular`. Someone on irc wanted something that I cannot quite recall at the moment--maybe extending into the outside margin on twosided documents--a month or so back. I've never actually used it myself in a document (I've never needed long tables), but it seems pretty good. I hope Johannes and Theo continue working on it, providing built in support for things like `multicols`. The bits of the code I've had to look at seem pretty well written and easy enough to follow.

Comment: Very nice. A minor problem: If you set `\columnseprule` you notice that the last column has a height of `\textheight`. Is there any way around that?

Comment: It works also from within LyX, though using TeX code inside an ERT box. Wonder if it is easy enough to trick LyX to use `begin{supertabular}` instead of `begin{tabular}`and, thus, create the table with LyX' respective GUI tools.

Comment: @TH.: This works pretty well, but it seems to break if a caption is added. That is, if a top caption is added then it is added in the first left column and the rest of that column is left empty. If a bottom caption is added then it is added at the bottom, but the first left column is left empty as well. Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour? I would like the caption to be printed at the bottom, while still filling the first column.

Answer (score 10):

What follows is a very crude solution to your main problem (lining up the rows properly): Use a `tabbing` environment. IIRC, there's no easy way to center the contents of a tabbing "cell", but column/page breaks inside a `tabbing` environment are permitted. The trick is to use `\\*` to forbid breaks after certain rows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol,xcolor}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\stnum{30} % number of items

\newcounter{mytabbing}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\setcounter{mytabbing}{0}
\begin{tabbing}
\rule{0.7in}{1pt} \= \rule{0.7in}{1pt} \= \rule{0.7in}{1pt} \kill
\whiledo{\value{mytabbing}<\stnum}{%
  \stepcounter{mytabbing}%
  \themytabbing  \> T \> F \\* % "\\" would produce an incorrect column break
  \> {\color{black!20}\rule{1.4in}{2.8ex}} \\
}
\end{tabbing}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've never before found a use for the tabbing environment. As for centering the T's and F's, that can be done by embedding them in a `tabular` environment: `\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{.5in}}T\end{tabular}` will do the trick.  Since there's a bounty, I'll wait a few days to see if any other solutions show up, but this is a pretty good solution to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, lockstep.  I've decided to accept TH's answer, since it allows for more flexibility in the formatting of the table, and also allows a header.  But the `\\*` was a very clever way of solving the problem.