# Strange interaction between natbib and algorithm2e

Tags: natbib, titlesec, incompatibility, algorithm2e

Here's a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[Bar(2011)]{bar}
Bar
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This produces a heading akin to

> *Bibliography

If `titlesec` is commented out, it fails to compile unless `natbib` is also commented out

If either `algorithm2e` or `natbib` are commented out, then it produces the heading

> ### References

I would clearly like to see the latter. Do I need to use another pseudocode package or can this be solved?

Comment: The mind works in mysterious ways! You can solve this problem: [multicolumn long table or enumeration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration), but package loading order escaped you today. :-)

Comment: @Alan: Ha! I didn't even think about changing package order. I was thinking about the algorithm my coauthor had written. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load `natbib` before `algorithm2e`.