# titlesec, hyperref, algorithm2e, and \appendix

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, titlesec, appendices, algorithm2e

When I use `titlesec`, `hyperref`, and `algorithm2e` together, sections after an `\appendix` are not numbered properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\appendix
\section{bar}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this gives the warning

> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{section.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

Sure enough, the .aux file shows

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}foo}{1}{section.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {A}bar}{1}{section.1}}
```

- Removing `titlesec` changes the second `section.1` to `appendix.1`.
- Removing `algorithm2e` changes the second `section.1` to `section.A`.
- Removing both changes the second `section.1` to `appendix.A`.

Unlike [last time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/strange-interaction-between-natbib-and-algorithm2e), I tried all six permutations of the packages but had no luck.

Can this combination of packages be made to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always good to load `hyperref` last. (But you're right, that won't solve your problem.) I think the main source of the problem is `algorithm2e`.  Based on  [this discussion](http://www.golatex.de/viewtopic,p,22014.html) (in German) here, it seems that there are a few possible solutions. The simplest two are:

Add

```
\renewcommand*{\theHsection}{\thesection}
```

after loading `hyperref`.

or

add

```
\let\chapter\undefined
```

after loading `algorithm2e`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\let\chapter\undefined % use this line
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
%\renewcommand*{\theHsection}{\thesection} % or this one
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\appendix
\section{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the best solution (per a Google translate) is `\let\chapter\undefined` after loading `algorithm2e`. As you note, I should have been loading `hyperref` last, and indeed I normally would. I just happened to start with lexicographic ordering of the packages to make sure I didn't miss any of the 6 permutations. t, h, a was the 6th permutation. =)

Comment: Yes, that will work too.  I read the post quite quickly and went for the first solution that worked.  I'll adjust my answer.