# How to refer to section numbers in a citation call-out?

Tags: bibtex, citing

In the example bellow, the citation call-out to entry 58 includes also the section 12.3.2. 
Is there a package or a built-in way to create call-outs in this format? I'm using bibtex to manage the bibliography.

[image]

For example, I expected that I could use a command like:

```
default graph \cite{foo}[12.3.2]. This...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you load the `natbib` citation management package (with the option `numbers`, since it looks like you use a numeric citation call-out style), you could issue the following citation command to achieve your objective:

```
\cite[\S12.3.2]{<foo>}
```

where `<foo>` is the key of the bib entry you wish to cite.

Here's the output of a minimal working example that illustrates these points:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abcdefgh.bib} 
@article{xyz,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = "3001",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  volume = "111",
  number = 1,
  pages  = "1-100",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\cite[\S12.3.2]{xyz}
\bibliography{abcdefgh}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found that `natlib` have some incompatibility with `algorithm2e`. I got an error when using both libraries in the same document.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/strange-interaction-between-natbib-and-algorithm2e

Comment: @DanielHernández - The solution is simple: be sure to load `natbib` *before* `algorithm2e`.

Comment: Thanks! My solution was including the package `titlesec` before both packages. Your solution is better.