# Making a long table continue over two columns

Tags: tables, two-column, multicol

I am using multicol to make a two-column document using the book document class. I have a long tabular that I want to break where the page breaks and then continue in the next column.

I could split it into two tables, but I want their width and such to be the same. I've tried with longtable but can't get it to work.

I basically want the table to split and arrange itself into two columns just like normal text does.

Edit: Sorry for the lack of information. With just 1 column it works fine with longtable, but when I use multicols it breaks down and just continues outside the page. I also get an error while compiling.

> Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.

This is a simplification of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
Header of first column & Header of second column \\
\endhead
Table cell 1, 1 & Table cell 1, 2 \\
Table cell 2, 1 & Table cell 2, 2 \\
Table cell 1, 1 & Table cell 1, 2 \\
...
...
\end{longtable}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: What it looks like]

I hope this is enough information. Any thoughts?

Comment: "I've tried with longtable but can't get it to work." is very little information. What exactly did not work with longtable? And are you able to post a [small, but complete example code](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html), so we are able to find the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multicolumn long table or enumeration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `\twocolumn` format, then you can use the package [`supertabular`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\tablehead{Header of first column & Header of second column \\}

\begin{supertabular}{ccc}
Table cell 1, 1 & Table cell 1, 2 \\
Table cell 2, 1 & Table cell 2, 2 \\
Table cell 1, 1 & Table cell 1, 2 \\
...
...
\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

together with the package `multicols` you can only use the `tabbing` environment.

Comment: +1 Was `supertabular` created to replace `longtable`?

Comment: no, it is another package. There are more packages which support a pagebreak

Comment: That's great. I did not know about supertabular. A shame it can't be used with multicols, but this works for my purpose.

Comment: +1 for the comment on `supertabular` not working with `multicols`.  it's too bad but it helps to know in advance before wasting hours trying to tweak the settings...

Answer (score 17):

A way to use `longtable` within `multicols` is described in one of the answers to [Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex). As multicol does balancing after the table is processed some of the features (like repeated table headings) will not work though.

A way to use `supertabular` with `multicols` is described in [Trick Supertabular into Multicols in new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105717/trick-supertabular-into-multicols-in-new-command).

The difference between the two table environments is that `supertabular` is calculating the table cell width anew for each column while `longtable`keeps them uniform.

Answer (score 5):

I already posted this answer in a similar question, but I used `minipage` and `vdots` and got the effect I wanted:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\caption{Your Caption}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical} \\
\midrule
0  &  0.0  &  7.88e-31   \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Cell} & \textbf{Simulation} & \textbf{Theoretical}  \\
\midrule
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
99  &  0.0  &  7.88-29  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]