# longtable does not work on ieeeconf, but works on Document class article

Tags: longtable, ieeeconf

I am trying to add a long table of figures into latex. I am able to successfully add in `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.

But when I try adding it in the following document class, I get error:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  


Error:

**Package longtable error: longtable not in 1-column mode \begin{longtable}**
```

The code for table I created is:

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-10cm}{}
\begin{longtable}{ccp{5cm}|}
\caption{results}\label{tab:support}\\
%Row1 __________________________________________________________________________
Image & result &My comments \\

\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=140px,height=120px]
{Images/support/rgb_000938.eps}}
&\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=200px,height=150px]
{Images/support/region_000938_1.eps}} & xxxx \\
\newline

\end{longtable}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{center}
```

Comment: In two column `longtable` doesn't work as of now. You may use `supertabular` instead.

Comment: Please have mercy to your readers and don't use tables on a conference paper that lasts more than one column or a page.

Answer (score 4):

longtable works in two columns if you use the code from

[multi-page two column table in a single column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74591/multi-page-two-column-table-in-a-single-column-document/87957#87957)

Note I used

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt,]{IEEEconf}
```

as that appears to be the class name with uppercase IEEE and `10pt` should have no space, and the version I have in TeXLive 2012 complained about the conference option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt,]{IEEEconf}  

\usepackage{longtable}


\makeatletter
\let\saved@longtable\longtable
\long\def\foo#1\LT@err#2#3#4!!{\def\longtable{#1#4}}
\expandafter\foo\longtable!!

\long\def\foo#1\@outputpage#2\@outputpage#3!!{%
\def\LT@output{#1\@opcol#2\@opcol#3}}
\expandafter\foo\LT@output!!
\makeatother

\begin{document}




\twocolumn[\section{List}]



\begin{longtable}{| l || c |}
\caption{Some square numbers\label{tab:xxx}}\\
$n$&$n$-squared\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
$n$&$n$-squared\\
\hline
\endhead
a&b\\\relax
\input{squares.tex}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```