# How to spread a table between two columns

Tags: tables, two-column

I read these posts:

1. [multi-page two column table in a single column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74591/multi-page-two-column-table-in-a-single-column-document?lq=1)
2. [Dealing with very long table - split into columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134381/dealing-with-very-long-table-split-into-columns?lq=1)

But still can not resolve my problem. Could you please help me to spread a table between two columns in a two column page, as such:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It would be particularly great to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) Welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option using a stationary `\captionof{table}{<caption>}` (from [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) or [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of)) and providing a manual split across table entries from one column to the next:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,graphicx,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure*}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Some really interesting picture.}
\end{figure*}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{The Vulnerable Assets}
\end{center}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|X}
  \hline
  \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Item and Description} \\
  \hline
  VA1 & \lipsum*[2] \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|X}
  \hline
  \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Item and Description} \\
  \hline
  VA2 & \lipsum*[4] \\
  \hline
  VA3 & \lipsum*[4] \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Then, a far more versatile edition using an enumeration, but without the perpetual horizontal rules (as suggested by [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,graphicx,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure*}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Some really interesting picture.}
\end{figure*}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{The Vulnerable Assets}
\end{center}
\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}
\noindent\leavevmode\hrulefill
\begin{enumerate}[label=VA\arabic*,align=left,labelwidth=2em,leftmargin=3em,labelsep=1em]
  \item[\textbf{No.}] \textbf{Item and Description}

  \item \lipsum*[7]

  \item \lipsum*[4]
\end{enumerate}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\noindent\leavevmode\hrulefill

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is just what I needed. Thank you very much! Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could vote it up, but apparently do not have enough reputation. I will vote it after I will gain some. Thank you again.