# How to fit a table into 2 columns in the format of a two colmns paper?

Tags: tables, two-column, paper-size, fit

I am a newcomer in Latex. I am writing a paper that normally has two columns. I put a table, and it was ok for the tables that I wanted to place in one column, but I want to add a table that fits into two columns. Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

```
    \documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Experimental Value of Components\label{tab:Comparison}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \cellcolor[gray]{0.95} Ref. & \cellcolor[gray]{0.95} Number of&Voltage Gain (G)&Duty Cycle Range&Maximum Voltage Stress on&Total Voltage Stress on Semiconductors&Low Pulsating Input Current&.&..&..&..\\
        \hline
        \hline
        Output Power, $P_{o}$  & 400 W&&&&&&&&&\\
        \hline
        Input-output voltage &&&&&&&&&& \\
        \hline
        & &&&&&&&&& \\
        \hline
        & &&&&&&&&& \\
        \hline
        &&&&&&&&&& \\
        \hline
        & &&&&&&&&&\\
        \hline
        &&&&&&&&&& \\
        \hline
        &&&&&&&&&& \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Usually this would be done with `\begin{table*}...`

Comment: I tried that, but I faced an error.

Comment: Look at Werner answer on this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176336/how-to-spread-a-table-between-two-columns?rq=1

Comment: Did you also put `\end{table*}`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a table that spans both columns. This is done by `table*` environment. Since you have also added `stfloats`, starred floats gain an additional argument `[b]`, which moves them to the bottom of a page.

Due to a large number of columns, I would suggest to reduce length of all headers, e.g. by substituting full phrases with acronyms and adding explanation at the bottom of a table (or in the text). While I suggest this approach, I also decided to use inline format in annotations because stacking everything vertically would take significant space of the table.
Alternatively, rotating headers by 90 degrees (requires `rotating`) might be an option but I haven't applied it here.

The example is based on `tabularray` (see the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)). For more complex tables, it provides much easier interface to achieve more demanding formatting.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
% \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
% \usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % Required only for dummy texts


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\kant[1]

\begin{table*}[b]
  \newcommand\hsep{\hspace{4em}} 
  \centering
  \begin{talltblr}[
      caption = {Experimental Value of Components},
      label = {tab:Comparison},
    ]
    {
      width=\textwidth,
      colspec = {@{} Q[3cm,m] X[c,m] *{9}{X[c,m]} @{}},
      row{1} = {c, font=\bfseries},
      column{2} = {bg=black!20},
      cell{1}{1-2} = {bg=black!10},
      cell{Z}{1} = {c=11}{},
    }
    \toprule
    Ref. & N (W) & VG & DCR & M. VS & T. VS & L. PIC & A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    Output Power, $P_{o}$ & 400 &&&&&&&&& \\
    Input-output voltage  & 500 &&&&&&&&& \\
    Xyz xyz xyz           & 600 &&&&&&&&& \\
    Xyz xyz xyz           & 700 &&&&&&&&& \\
    Xyz xyz xyz           & 800 &&&&&&&&& \\
    \bottomrule
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\linespread{1.21}\selectfont%
      \mbox{N: Number of ... (W)}\hsep
      \mbox{VG: Voltage Gain (G)}\hsep
      \mbox{DCR: Duty Cycle Range}\hsep
      \mbox{M.VS: Maximum Voltage Stress on ...}\hsep
      \mbox{T.VS: Total Voltage Stress on ...}\hsep
      \mbox{L.PIC: Low Pulsating Input Current}\hsep
      \mbox{A: Explanation for A}\hsep
      \mbox{B: Explanation for B}\hsep
      \mbox{C: Explanation for C}\hsep
      \mbox{D: Explanation for D}\hsep
    }
  \end{talltblr}
\end{table*}

\kant[2-5]
\end{document}
```