# supertabular always results in 'Misplaced \noalign' error

Tags: supertabular

I'm trying to use the package `supertabular`in order to be able to break long tables in twocolumn mode (cf. [the answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/making-a-long-table-continue-over-two-columns)). But I always end up with the following error when compiling:

```
 Misplaced \noalign.
\@tabletail ->\noalign 
                       {\global \let \@savcr =\\ \global \let \\=\org@tabula...
l.9 \end{supertabular}
```

I assume I'm making some very basic mistake here, but I can't figure out what it is. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}{l l}
First column & Second column\\
First column & Second column\\
First column & Second column
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You must end the last line with an ``\\`` too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`supertabular` requires *all* rows to end in `\\` (with normal tabular the last ones doesn't need it, although you could supply it there too). So add `\\`to the last row.