# Trick Supertabular into Multicols in new command

Tags: macros, multicol, supertabular

I'm using `supertabular` in `multicols` enviroment using this trick

```
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
        \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
        \columnbreak
    \else
        \mcnewpage
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

I'd like to put that code into `\newcommand` - I've tried this:

```
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
        \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
        \columnbreak
    \else
        \mcnewpage
    \fi
}
\makeatother
}
```

but when i use my `\newcommand` it doesn't work - table is in only one column.
What is the right way to define this command?

EDIT: examples

this works fine but i generate multiple multicols in the document so I want to put that trick code into single line comand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular,multicol}

\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<100
        \advance\n by1
        \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                \textbf{\number\n.}& shortText
                \tabularnewline
        }
\repeat
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\newpage{%
        \if@firstcolumn
                \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
                \columnbreak
        \else
                \mcnewpage
        \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{supertabular}{|l|l|}
\tablebody
\end{supertabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

and this doesn't work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular,multicol}

\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<100
        \advance\n by1
        \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                \textbf{\number\n.}& shortText
                \tabularnewline
        }
\repeat
\makeatother

\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\newpage{%
        \if@firstcolumn
                \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
                \columnbreak
        \else
                \mcnewpage
        \fi
}
\makeatother
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols
\begin{supertabular}{|l|l|}
\tablebody
\end{supertabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should go as the first and last line respectively (outside the definition of `\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols`). Also `\let\mcnewpage\newpage` should go outside, but it's not as relevant.

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (also non working, actually) is needed.

Comment: I'm trying to use the first code that you have added. When I add it above my `supertabular` that starts in the middle of page 18, resulting file stops at page 17. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular,multicol}

\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<100
        \advance\n by1
        \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                \textbf{\number\n.}& shortText
                \tabularnewline
        }
\repeat

\makeatletter
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{%
  \renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
      \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
      \columnbreak
    \else
      \mcnewpage
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols
\begin{supertabular}{|l|l|}
\tablebody
\end{supertabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

You have to put `\makeatother` and `\makeatletter` outside the macro definition.

Comment: Oh it really works, i've tried that as you suggested in comment but i must have made some mistake

Comment: Quite impressive and very useful, but I have some issues with long text. The second column overlaps on the first one. The text does not seem to break and go on a new line. I put a MWE [here](https://pastebin.com/wbkGVgEV) if you are able to take a look.

Comment: @Lalylulelo Text in `l` columns doesn't break across lines. By the way, you'd need *very* large text width to accommodate three columns.