# Line break with supertabular won't work

Tags: line-breaking, multicol, supertabular

So, I have a really long list of symbols that I decided to create with `supertabular`.  I'd like the table to split as it goes over to the second column, so I used `{multicols}{2}` but I found out that it conflicted with the supertabular package. So I used [Trick Supertabular into Multicols in new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105717/trick-supertabular-into-multicols-in-new-command), and it worked! But the formatting is wrong in some places.. in the first page for exemple the text is far form the symbol (only in the second column) and the line breaks won't work either.. so, any suggestions on how to fix these problems? Or maybe another way of doing what I want... Thank you so much!!

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<100
        \advance\n by1
        \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                \textbf{\number\n.}& shortText
                \tabularnewline
        }
\repeat

\makeatletter
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{%
  \renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
      \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
      \columnbreak
    \else
      \mcnewpage
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols

\begin{supertabular}{ll}
$\alpha$ & Ângulo de ataque [$\degree$]  \\
$\alpha_{0w}$ & Ângulo de {\it lift} 0 da asa relativo a linha de referencia da fuselagem [$\degree$]  \\
$\beta$ & Ângulo de derrapagem [$\degree$] \\
$\gamma$ & Gradiente adiabático [K/m] \\
$\delta$ & Deflexão do profundor [$\degree$] \\
$\varepsilon$ & Ângulo de {\it downwash} [rad] \\
$\varepsilon_0$ & Ângulo de {\it downwash} para $\alpha_0$ [rad] \\
$\eta$ & Fator de eficiência \\
$\theta$ & Movimento de torçao [rad] \\
$\xi$ & Fator de amortecimento \\
$\rho$ & Densidade do ar [kg/m$^3$] \\
$\omega_{\theta}$ & Frequencia natural de torçao [Hz] \\
$\omega_h$ & Frequencia natural de flexão [Hz] \\
$\omega_{n}$ & Frequencia natural não amortecida [Hz] \\
AR & {\it Aspect Ratio} \\
$b$ & Envergadura da asa [mm] \\
$CP$ & Carga paga [kg] \\
$C_L$ & Coeficiente de sustentação \\
$C_{L \alpha w}$ & {\it Slope} da asa [rad$^-1$] \\
$C_{L \alpha t}$ & {\it Slope} da cauda [rad$^-1$] \\
$C_{L0w}$ & Coeficiente de {\it lift} da asa para AOA nulo \\
$C_{m}$ & Coeficiente de momento \\
$C_{m \alpha}$ & Derivada do coeficiente do momento em
relação ao ângulo de ataque [rad$^-1$] \\
$C_{m \alpha f}$ & Derivada do coeficiente de momento em
relação ao ângulo de ataque da fuselagem [rad$^-1$] \\
$C_{m \alpha w}$ & Derivada do coeficiente de momento em
relação ao ângulo de ataque da asa [rad$^-1$] \\
$C_{m \alpha t}$ & Derivada do coeficiente de momento em
relação ao ângulo de ataque da cauda [rad$^-1$] \\
$C_{m \alpha cw}$ & Coeficiente de momento do centro
aerodinâmico \\
$C_{m0}$ & Coeficiente de momento para ângulo de
ataque 0$\degree$ \\
$C_{m0f}$ & Coeficiente de momento para 0$\degree$ de
ângulo de ataque da fuselagem \\
$C_{m0w}$ & Coeficiente de momento para ângulo
de ataque 0$\degree$ \\
$C_{m0t}$ & Derivada do coeficiente de momento \\
em relação ao ângulo de ataque da cauda [rad$^-1$] \\
\end{supertabular}
```

And the list goes on...