# floating multipage two-column supertabular

Tags: tables, two-column, supertabular

I have a long but narrow table. To save some spaces, I'm trying to place a table spanning over multiple two-column pages, but I need help with floating as the table starts from the next page. I want it to start right after the section title. Here is MWE (I shortened the table with ...):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{supertabular}


%HERE WE GO

\begin{document}
\section{Past AP Free Response Questions by Topic}

\twocolumn

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'AP Index'
    \begin{supertabular}{llll}
    \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Part} & Sec \\
    1998  & AB2 BC2 & c     & 0. \\
    1999  & BC6   & d     & 0. \\
    2000  & AB6   & b     & 0. \\
    2000  & AB6   & b     & 0. \\
    2006  & AB3   & c     & 0. \\
    2001  & BC5   & a     & 1.2 \\
    2000  & BC4   & d     & 1.3 \\
    2006  & BC3   & d     & 1.3 \\
    ...
    \end{supertabular}%
\end{document}
```

The table does span over two columns and pages as expected but the only problem is, as mentioned, it starts after the section title which is huge waste of space. Is there any way to make it start after the title? So far I've tried few options with "float" package after wrapping the whole supertabular with another 1x1 table but without success.

EDIT: I found my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105717/trick-supertabular-into-multicols-in-new-command!)!!

Comment: please don't edit answers in to the question, post an answer or vote to close as duplicate (I didn't see your edit until after I'd posted an answer)

Answer (score 1):

`supertabular` does not float, and latex does not support multi-page floats at all. The issue here is that `\twocolumn` starts a new page.  use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{supertabular}


%HERE WE GO

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\section{Past AP Free Response Questions by Topic}]



% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'AP Index'
    \begin{supertabular}{llll}
    \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Part} & Sec \\
    1998  & AB2 BC2 & c     & 0. \\
    1999  & BC6   & d     & 0. \\
    2000  & AB6   & b     & 0. \\
    2000  & AB6   & b     & 0. \\
    2006  & AB3   & c     & 0. \\
    2001  & BC5   & a     & 1.2 \\
    2000  & BC4   & d     & 1.3 \\
    2006  & BC3   & d     & 1.3 \\
    \end{supertabular}%
\end{document}
```