# The long table in the multi-column

Tags: longtable, multicol, supertabular

I have a long table And because it occupies a lot of pages, I want to print three columns per page, so the number of pages is too small. I used From the environment

```
   multicols
```

But it has no effect on the output. I also have to say that I do not want to make the whole text, for example, three pillars, but only this long table, I would like to put three pillars. I also want to repeat its header in every part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}


\begin{multicols}{3}

\tablefirsthead{%
\hline
ZERO-POINT&$G$  \\
\hline}
\tablehead{%
\hline
ZERO-POINT&$G$ \\
\hline}
\tabletail{%
\hline
}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\tablecaption{}
\begin{supertabular}{cc}
\hline
$0$ & smw \\
\hline
$1$ & Hmd \\
\hline
$2$ & rbb \\
    \hline
    $3$ & Elm \\
.
.
.
.
$1350$ & nfv \\ 
    \hline
    $1351$ & wsws \\
   \hline
    \end{supertabular}%
\end{multicols}


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134381/156344). In short: the best way is to put them in different tables.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105736/134144 might also be interesting.