# How to automatically typeset a table in three columns?

Tags: tables, xetex, multicolumn

With the following, I can get a table in "two columns" - it is possible to make it three?

It is possible by splitting the whole table by human hand, but there should be some automatic solutions.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xtab,booktabs}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.
 
\begin{document}
\topcaption{This is top caption}
\bottomcaption{This is bottom caption}
\tablecaption{this is table caption}
\tablefirsthead{\toprule First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} \\ \midrule}
%
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries  Continued from previous column}} \\
\toprule
First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}\\ \midrule}
%
\tabletail{%
\midrule \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \midrule}
\tablelasttail{%
\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule}
\begin{xtabular}{ll}
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes here too \\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text
\end{xtabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have specified 2 `\begin{xtabular}{ll}` you need three `\begin{xtabular}{lll}`

Comment: Are you referring to the two columns in your table or to the fact that that your whole table is split into two columns due to the `twocolumn` document class option? Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis Oh, I really haven't excepted that there is a misunderstanding here ... The table in the code has two columns, and I've specified [twocolumn], now I've got a table of two columns formatted in a two-column-page, then I would like to make it into a three-column-page.

Comment: What about the rest of your document? Do you want text surrounding the table to also be split up into three columns or just this particular table?

Comment: @leandriis It would be great if only the particular table was split up into three columns, and it can be assumed that the document is consisted of one table, and with no else other elements.

Comment: Probably, you could make use of the `multicol` package to split up your page into three columns and combine this with `\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols`  as for example shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105736/134144

Comment: @leandriis It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@leandriis gave out the solution in the comments:

> Probably, you could make use of the multicol package to split up your page into three columns and combine this with \TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols as for example shown here: tex.stackexchange.com/a/105736/134144
>
> – leandriis Mar 27 at 13:20