# longtabu with multicols?

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, multicol, tabu

I want to place a very long table into my document, i.e. a table which spans multiple pages. The table has a rather narrow width, so it should be set in multicolumn mode (2 or 3 columns). The text should be set in 1-column mode, of course.

For my tables, I use the "tabu" and "longtabu" tables. Unfortunately, longtabu does not work together with multicols. The error message is: "longtable not in 1-column mode..."

Is there any workaround?

The final table should look like in the sketch below. Please note how the entries should be ordered, and how the columns should be balanced on the last page of the table (although this is not absolutely necessary).

I'm grateful for any advice on how to achieve that!

[image]

Comment: `longtabu` uses `longtable` which can't be used inside `multicols` as stated in its documentation. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/making-a-long-table-continue-over-two-columns

Comment: Sure, that's why I'm asking for a workaround or alternative.

Comment: In the linked questions there are workarounds

Comment: Well, the workaround in the first question allows you to use longtabu in two-column-mode, but it does not add the longtabu headers! Neither at the column breaks nor at the page breaks. That renders longtabu rather useless..

Comment: Use supertabular, which works inside multicols and you are done. Receipt: see the links provided by egreg. Where is the problem?

Comment: In the links provided by egreg, it says that supertabular does NOT work with multicols!:

"together with the package multicols you can only use the tabbing environment."

"+1 for the comment on supertabular not working with multicols. it's too bad but it helps to know in advance before wasting hours trying to tweak the settings..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cals` tables work to some extent inside `multicols`. The limitation is that you have to specify table breaks manually.

[image: calstable in multicols]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,cals}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\section{Multipage table (in a multicols in a table)}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{1cm}{7cm}{1cm}}
\brow \cell{x} \cell{x} \cell{x} \erow
\brow \cell{x} \cell{
\columnsep=0cm\relax
% Force multicols to regard our \leftskip
% by pretending that we are a list.
\@totalleftmargin=\cals@paddingL\relax
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{calstable}
\alignR
\colwidths{{1.5cm}{1.5cm}}
\thead{\brow \cell{$n$}\cell{$n^2$} \erow}
\tfoot{\brow \cell{$n$}\cell{$n^2$} \erow}
\brow \cell{2}  \cell{4}   \erow
\brow \cell{3}  \cell{9}   \erow
\brow \cell{4}  \cell{16}  \erow
\brow \cell{5}  \cell{25}  \erow
\brow \cell{6}  \cell{36}  \erow
\tbreak{\break }
\brow \cell{7}  \cell{49}  \erow
\brow \cell{8}  \cell{64}  \erow
\brow \cell{9}  \cell{81}  \erow
\brow \cell{10} \cell{100} \erow
\brow \cell{11} \cell{121} \erow
\end{calstable}

\end{multicols}
} \cell{x} \erow
\brow \cell{x} \cell{x} \cell{x} \erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice, but manually specifiying the table breaks is not an option in this case.