# Supertabular + minipage

Tags: tables, longtable, minipage

I have a very long but narrow table (3 columns but 800 rows) and I would like to have it such that the table starts on the left side of the page and breaks onto the right side of the page before breaking again to continue on the left of a new page and so froth. I've tried `supertabular` but I'm not too sure how to proceed with `minipage`. (Perhaps it's not even the right option?) I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Hope the diagram helps.

```
PAGE 1
row 1    row m+1
.        .
.        .
.        .
row m    row n

PAGE 2
row n+1  row k+1
.        .
.        .
.        .
row k    row l
```

Edit: I've implemented the code as such

```
\twocolumn
\bgroup
\centering
\tablefirsthead{\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c|} $d$ & $L_d(1)$ & $L_{2d}(1)$ \\ \hline}
\tablehead{\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c|} d & $L_d(1)$ & $L_{2d}(1)$ \\ \hline}
\tabletail{\hline}

%
\begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|} \hline

1   &   0.655514389 &   0.927037339 \\  
3   &   1.513845635 &   0   \\  
5   &   0   &   1.658334806 \\  
7   &   0   &   0   \\  
11  &   0.790580099 &   0   \\  
etc.
\end{supertabular}
\par
\egroup
\onecolumn
```

But encountered a problem, I was unable to put the `d` in the first column of the table heads into math mode without breaking the code. See errors below:

```
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\@preamble ...ignorespaces \@sharp \unskip \hfil }
\hskip \tabcolsep \hskip -...
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.629 \begin{supertabular}{|c| c |c|}
\hline
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

Comment: Will using the `multicols` package help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398127/breaking-a-list-into-multiple-columns-in-latex 
If not, can you include a MWE with what you've tried so far, especially with `minipage`?

Comment: `multicol` could work, but I understand that `supertabular` and `multicol` are incompatible, see comments to answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/making-a-long-table-continue-over-two-columns

Comment: I haven't tried anything with `minipage` because I have no idea how to start :P terribly sorry darthbith!

Comment: Oh, I have the data on excel and I've cunningly used Notepad++ to replace `tabs` by `tabs & tabs` and `\r\n` by `\\ \r\n`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\twocolumn` with `supertabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3in, bottom = 3in, left = 1in, right = 1in,heightrounded]{geometry}  % only for this document, this border.
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}  % just for fun
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\myrows{%
 & 23 & 45 \\
 & 56 & 87 \\
 & 23 & 45 \\
 & 56 & 87 \\
 & 23 & 45 \\
 & 56 & 87 
}
\newcommand\Myrow{%
    \myrows\\
    \myrows\\
    \myrows\\
    \myrows\\
    \myrows\\
    \myrows\\
    \myrows
    }
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
%==================================================================
\begin{document}
%===============================================================
%This is some dummy text just for demo used here. It is in one column mode.
\twocolumn
\bgroup
\centering
\tablefirsthead{\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textnumero}& Name& number \\ \hline}
%
\tablehead{
%\multicolumn{3}{c}%
%{{\bfseries  Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textnumero}& Name & number\\ \hline}
%
\tabletail{
\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline}
%
\tablelasttail{
\\\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ \hline}
%
\begin{supertabular}{|>{\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.}c|c|c|}\hline
    \Myrow\\
    \Myrow
\end{supertabular}%
\par
\egroup
\onecolumn
This is some dummy text just for demo used here. It is in one column mode.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer!
Used it but I hadn't seen the `tabletail` appearing at the end of the column (not page) break at first. Has anyone found a way to get around this one?

Comment: @Maugan Thanks. You didn't get `tabletail`? Did you run the above code as such?

Comment: I do get the table tail but it does appear, from what I can observe, where supertabular sees a page break, which corresponds to every column end (see after n°23: "Continued on next page"... which is in fact on the same page).

It is not of much interest (I just removed the `tabletail` in my code) but I guess some people who would like to do it more elegantly might be interested in the answer.

Comment: @Maugan: `supertabular` sees `\columnbreak` as `\pagebreak`. No distinction. Hence to get `in the next column` and `in the next page` one has to do more with `supertabular`. :-(