# Two columns per page - longtable*

Tags: longtable

Dears, good morning.

How can I leave the following arrangement in the form of two columns per page? That is the pattern of the model I am using. The command is:

```
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}
\noindent\begin{longtable*}{@{}l @{\quad=\quad} l@{}}

$A$ & surface area, $\mathrm{m^{2}}$  \\
$\hat{C}_{p}$ & heat capacity at constant pressure, $\mathrm{J/(kg.K)}$    \\
$\hat{C}_{v}$ & heat capacity at constant volume, $\mathrm{J/(kg.K)}$    \\
$C_{\varepsilon 1}$ & empirical constant of $\kappa-\varepsilon$ model \\
$C_{\varepsilon 2}$ & empirical constant of $\kappa-\varepsilon$ model \\
$C_{\mu}$ & empirical constant of $\kappa-\varepsilon$ model \\
$E_{b}$ & blackbody emissive power, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$   \\
$F_{ij}$ & view factor \\
$\boldsymbol{g}$ & gravity acceleration, $\mathrm{m/s^{2}}$   \\
$G$ & incident radiation or irradiation, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$   \\
$G_{0}$ & external radiation that reaches the surface in analysis, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$   \\
$H$ & reference physical domain height, $\mathrm{m}$  \\
$I$ & intensity of radiation, $\mathrm{W/(m^{2}.sr)}$   \\
${k_{t}}$ & thermal conductivity, W/(m.K)   \\
$p_{-} r g h$ & absolute dynamic pseudo-pressure, $\mathrm{Pa}$ \\
$P$ & absolute total pressure, $\mathrm{Pa}$    \\
$\bar{P}$ & component average of pressure in the RANS model, $\mathrm{Pa}$     \\
$Pr$ & Prandtl number \\
$Pr_{t}$ & turbulent Prandtl number \\
$q_{conv}$ & convective heat flux, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$  \\
$q_{net}$ & net heat flux, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$  \\
$q_{rad}$ & radiative heat flux, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$  \\
$\bar{q}^{(v)}$ & viscous heat flux, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$  \\
$\bar{q}^{(t)}$ & turbulent heat flux, $\mathrm{W/m^{2}}$  \\
$r$ & radius, $\mathrm{m}$  \\
$R$ & gas constant, $\mathrm{J/(kg.K)}$    \\
$Ra_{H}$ & Rayleigh number calculated with the height as characteristic length  \\
$t$ & time, $\mathrm{s}$   \\
$T$ & temperature, $\mathrm{K}$     \\
$\bar{T}$ & average temperature, $\mathrm{K}$     \\
$\tilde{T}$ & component average of temperature in the RANS model, $\mathrm{K}$     \\
$\boldsymbol{u}$ & velocity vector, $\mathrm{m/s}$     \\
$\overline{u_{\imath}^{\prime} T^{\prime}}$ & turbulent fluctuations in the RANS model, $\mathrm{(m.K)/s}$\\
$\bar{u}$ & average components of velocity in the RANS model, $\mathrm{m/s}$   \\
$u_{}^{\prime}$ & floating components of velocity in the RANS model, $\mathrm{m/s}$   \\
$U$ & velocity field OpenFOAM® parameter, $\mathrm{m/s}$  \\
$\hat{U}$ & specific internal energy, $\mathrm{J/kg}$    \\
$x$ & x coordinate, $\mathrm{m}$   \\
$y$ & y coordinate, $\mathrm{m}$     \\
$z$ & z coordinate, $\mathrm{m}$     \\
$z^{*}$ & elevation, $\mathrm{m}$ \\

$\alpha$ & under-relaxation factor \\
$\alpha_{t}$ & turbulent thermal diffusivity, $\mathrm{m^{2}/s}$ \\
$\beta$    & thermal coefficient of volume expansion, $\mathrm{K^{-1}}$ \\
$\delta_{i j}$    & Kronecker’s delta function\\
$\epsilon $   & emissivity \\
$\varepsilon $    & dissipation rate of turbulent kinetic energy, $\mathrm{{m^{2}}/{s^{3}}}$ \\
$\theta$    & polar angle, $\mathrm{rad}$ \\
$\kappa$    & turbulent kinetic energy, $\mathrm{{m^{2}}/{s^{2}}}$ \\
$\mu$    & dynamic viscosity, kg/(m.s)\\
$\mu _{t}$    & turbulence dynamic viscosity, kg/(m.s) \\
$\nu$    & kinematic viscosity, $\mathrm{m^{2}/s}$ \\
$\nu_{t}$    & turbulence kinematic viscosity, $\mathrm{m^{2}/s}$ \\
$\rho$    & fluid density, $\mathrm{kg/m^{3}}$ \\
$\bar{\rho}$ & fluid density evaluated in $\bar{T}$, $\mathrm{kg/m^{3}}$ \\
$\sigma_{\varepsilon}$    & empirical constant of $\kappa-\varepsilon$ model \\
$\sigma_{\kappa}$    & empirical constant of $\kappa-\varepsilon$ model \\
$\bar{\Phi}_{v}^{(v)}$    & viscous dissipation function, $\mathrm{s^{-2}}$ \\
$\bar{\Phi}_{v}^{(t)}$    & turbulent energy dissipation function, $\mathrm{s^{-2}}$  \\
$\Omega$    & solid angle, $\mathrm{sr}$  \\

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\emph{Subscripts}}\\
$i$ & counter or index of summation \\
$j$ & counter or index of summation \\

\end{longtable*}}
```

The following error is pointed out on the 2nd line:

> Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode. Overfull
> \hbox (80.39828 pt too wide) in alignment at lines 516--537

I appreciate everyone's attention and help.

Best regards.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/making-a-long-table-continue-over-two-columns help?

Comment: I would need the content of the code, when it reached the end of the 1st column of the page, to go to the top of the 2nd column of the same page. With the current code it goes to the next page.

Thus:

https://ibb.co/LPKxpzr

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would really help here. There are multiple ways to achieve a two column layout, thus possible solutions depend on the method you currently use.

Comment: unrelated but putting `\noindent` before `longtable` just forces a spurious white empty line before it.  longtable does not support two column mode as the error  says. Also longtable package does not define a `longtable*` enviornment so you must be using some unnamed extension package, please always provide a compleet small document not a fragment where we have to guess how to make it work and see the issue.