# column header for multicols

Tags: multicol

I would like to add a fixed content (produced by e.g. `\parbox`) at the top of every column of a `multicols*` environment. How can I do this? The optional argument of `multicols*` is only added on the first page and covers all columns - I need it on every page and every column. Using a table package like `longtable` could be a solution but I haven't found a multipage tabular package that works well with `multicol`.

Comment: You can't use longtable in combination with `multicol`. `multicol` saves the content inside a save box and split them. `longtable` works well with `twocolumn` mode so you have the first method. (Note: `\twocolumn` always starts a new page). What to you want to have? Do you want to break at special points?

Comment: you can redefine the header of pagestyle francy} via the optional argument of `multicols`. With a \vbox of 0pt you can set the multicols header deeper than the default header.

Comment: @Herbert: That's my current solution (put the fixed content into the page header). But it looks bad if there is only one column on the last page (I use `multicols*`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide a minimal example, so I hope to get away by reminding you on this:

[multicolumn long table or enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration)

As far as I understand your question, you could use `\tablehead` of supertabular to print your »fixed content«.

Comment: Yes, that seems to to the trick. I'll wait till the end of the bounty period, though.