# Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicol

I would like to put some longer tabular data inside the multicols environment while maintaining its balancing abilities. I have tried supertabular with the trick to redefine `\newpage` as `columnbreak`. This isn't good though, because the columns aren't properly balanced. Finally I ended up using `\halign`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multicol}

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\par}

\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}
\def\mybreak{\hrule width \columnwidth height 0pt \columnbreak}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\shortlipsum
\medskip

% % This doesn't balance the columns. Whole table ends up in the left column (it fits)
% \begingroup\let\newpage\mybreak
% \noindent\begin{supertabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\indent}l l l}
% \tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
% \end{supertabular*}
% \endgroup

\begingroup\let\\\cr
\noindent\halign{\indent#\quad&#\quad&#\hfil\cr
\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines}
\endgroup

\medskip
\shortlipsum
\end{multicols}
\shortlipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I was wondering if I'm the only one using `\halign` to achieve this result. On the other hand `supertabular` leaves me with an undesired almost empty right column. How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't want `longtable` to add headers and footers to the table at the same time that `multicol` is balancing where to make the break (which would require that frank and I cooperate:-) then multicol will balance the output from longtable if you first trick `longtable` into thinking that it isn't in `multicol` at all.

I added some rules, just to show that latex tabular features then work, which is harder to do with a bare `\halign`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\par}

\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}


\begin{document}





\begin{multicols}{2}
\shortlipsum
\medskip

\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
\makeatletter\col@number\@ne
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
\end{longtable}
\unskip
\unpenalty
\unpenalty}

\unvbox\ltmcbox




\medskip
\shortlipsum
\end{multicols}
\shortlipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would never suspect this to work! I may even overlook the runaway vrule at the second "Lorem". :)  If longtable works then maybe longtabu will work as well. Still, it's good to see a familiar table environment and not have to dive into hrule texnicalities. :)

Comment: I mean "\halign". And as for the odd extra vrule, I don't get it in my pdf, so it must have been some dead pixels in the screenshot.

Comment: It really does work across multiple pages with both plain longtable and longtabu. Only things like `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, `\endlastfoot` **don't appear at all**.

Comment: the only thing LT could do with the *head and *foot commands is put either head or firsthead at the start and and either foot or lastfoot at the end, no chance of it doing anything at the break. So really no point in doing anything at all (as you can just put the lines in the table body) but it might be kinder to support that, as it makes it easier to move existing longtables into this useage,

Comment: I kindly ask for Frank and you (or someone else from the LaTeX3 team) to spend some time together again to fix this for LaTeX3: I want true mini pages in multicolumn mode, i.e. columns with separate headers and footers. And of course balanced (or not, if I want). The [last time I looked at this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32034/5763) the best option for this was to use `pdfpages`. I'm quite sure that this has been possible with ConTeXt for years, though.

Comment: @Frg, @DavidCarlisle: I am getting oodles of `! Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.` errors when I use this trick. Is this expected?

Comment: @wilx no `\makeatletter\col@number\@ne` tells LT it _is_ in one column mode.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have made it work but I am seeing some artifacts, like text being hidden/disappearing. I will try to prepare a MWE for a separate question later today.

Comment: This solution also works in Lyx: set the table as multi-page table (so that it uses longtable), place it inside a table float, and input the code given here at the beginning and the end of the table float (around the longtable, just like in the code snippet here).

Comment: Is it possible to make it so the `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot` can be respected, for those who don't need the columns balanced (using either `twocolumn` document setting or `multicols*` environment)?

Comment: @KeithDavies anything's possible, but not for free like the answer here, Supporting two column is probably a matter of duplicating the existing one col code adapting for two col. Supporting multicol's balanced columns would probably need a complete redesign

Comment: I can understand that. I have been able to get it to render the longtable in `multicols` environment and in `twocolumn`, but see only the single header (with the column names). This is as described, so I wasn't surprised. I realize and understand why the solution here doesn't present the other elements in (balanced) `multicols`... but I wonder if it's possible to make them appear if the columns don't need to balance. Sadly, I lack the depth of knowledge to quickly solve this one...

Comment: How can one define an environment so this can be easily (re)used within a document (say, `\begin{multicolstable}{2}{|l|l|l|}\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\end{multicolstable}`)? I tried using `\newenvironment` and `environ`’s `\NewEnviron`, but I get error messages.

Answer (score 4):

Package such as `longtable` and `supertabular` or, better than the latter, `xtab`, aim at overcoming a "limitation" of the TeX engine: tabular material has to be entirely read in to find the column widths. For huge tables this may easily lead to memory problems.

Unfortunately, `longtable` is incompatible with the `multicols` environment while, as you discovered, `supertabular` (and `xtab`) don't maintain the same column width across pages. Using `tabular` is impossible, as its implementation locks the material into a box *and* inside `\mathon` and `\mathoff` items so it's unbreakable.

For a simple table where you can figure out the column width, you can use `tabbing`, which splits across pages and columns:

```
\begin{tabbing}
Test \quad\= 99\quad\=\kill
Test \> \hfil 1  \> Description ... \\
...
Test \> \hfil 30 \> Description ...
\end{tabbing}
```

For more complex tables I'm afraid that the lower level `\halign` can be, at the moment, the more flexible solution.

Comment: I haven't tested that but couldn't you use the header line (with some invisible data) that supertabular inserts on each page to force certain column widths? That would force you to decide the column widths manually per column but it should then get them uniform (hopefully).

Comment: If one has to repeat data on the top (or bottom) of each column, the `xtab` solution is presently the only one. Probably forcing the header or footer to have the desired width can guarantee uniformity (but it defeats the principle that column width are computed from the data).

Comment: yes of course. it is kind of turning supertabular into a tabbing environment of sorts. but might be better than nothing and as you say longtable doesn't work as it deploys the outputroutine for its work

Comment: Something to be added to `xor`, of course. ;-) Also the `\mathon` and `\mathoff` items should be taken away from `tabular` when not necessary for "center alignment" so with some `\lastbox` trickery one could dismantle a `tabular` row by row.

Comment: I see a stripped version of tabular coming up. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an environment definition that will allow you to set long tables in
multi-column environments (with either the `multicols` environment or the
traditional `\twocolumn` declarations). It’s also compatible with vanilla
`longtable` but also packages like [`tabu`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu?lang=en) (for features like
growing/shrinking paragraph columns), ltxtable, etc.

Note that some `longtable` features, like headers and footers at page / column
breaks, will be absent, but it *mostly* works.

```
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newenvironment{fakelongtable}
        {\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
        \csname @twocolumnfalse\endcsname
        \csname col@number\endcsname\csname @ne\endcsname}
        {\unskip\unpenalty\unpenalty\egroup\unvbox\ltmcbox}
```

Example usage:

```
\begin{fakelongtable}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
        \tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
    \end{longtable}
\end{fakelongtable}
```

Comment: The column is not balanced!