# Typesetting Supertabular in two columns

Tags: tables, two-column

The problem is how to typeset **supertabular** in two columns. Really, I didn't understand the solution in [Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex).

As you see in the picture below, first, the **supertabular** begins from the right column and second, it's continue in next page, not in the other column.

[image: Supertabular in two columns - fail]

Please, use XeLaTeX to launch the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS PMincho}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.1ex}

\usepackage{fmultico}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{文法字引表薄い}{rgb}{0.99,0.91,0.85}
\definecolor{文法字引表濃い}{rgb}{0.99,0.83,0.7}
\definecolor{文法字引表見出し}{rgb}{0.99,0.91,0.85}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{文法字引表薄い}{文法字引表濃い}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{supertabular}{|m{25mm}|m{57mm}|} \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{文法字引表見出し} \bfseries\qquad \ruby{品詞}{ひんし}・Части речи} \\ \hline\hline
\ruby{動詞}{どうし} & \emph{глагол} \\ \hline
動詞I & \emph{глагол 1 группы} \\ \hline
動詞II & \emph{глагол 2 группы} \\ \hline
\ruby{自動詞}{じどうし} & \emph{непереходный глагол} \\ \hline
\ruby{他動詞}{たどうし} & \emph{переходный глагол} \\ \hline
\ruby{意思}{いし}\ruby{表示}{ひょうじ}動詞 & \emph{волевой (волеизъявительный глагол)} \\ \hline
\ruby{無}{む}意思表示動詞 & \emph{неволевой (неволеизъявительный) глагол} \\ \hline
\ruby{形容詞}{けいようし} & \emph{прилагательное} \\ \hline
い形容詞 & \emph{предикативное прилагательное} \\ \hline
な形容詞 & \emph{полупредикативное прилагательное} \\ \hline
\ruby{名詞}{めいし} & \emph{существительное} \\ \hline
\ruby{用言}{ようげん} & \emph{изменяемые части речи(動詞＋い形容詞)} \\ \hline
\ruby{体言}{たいげん} & \emph{неизменяемые части речи(名詞＋な形容詞)} \\ \hline
\ruby{副詞}{ふくし} & \emph{наречие} \\ \hline
\ruby{助詞}{じょし} & \emph{частица} \\ \hline
\ruby{接続詞}{せつぞくし} & \emph{союз} \\ \hline
\ruby{疑問視}{ぎもんし} & \emph{вопросительное слово} \\ \hline
\ruby{助数詞}{じょすうし} & \emph{счётный суффикс} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{文法字引表見出し} \bfseries\qquad \ruby{品詞}{ひんし}の\ruby{形}{けい}・Формы частей речи} \\ \hline\hline
X\ruby{本}{ほん} & \emph{функциональная основа, X=1,2,3,4,5} \\ \hline
\ruby{普通形}{ふつうけい} & \emph{простая форма} \\ \hline
\ruby{丁寧形}{ていねいけい} & \emph{нейтрально-вежливая форма} \\ \hline
\ruby{辞書形}{じしょけい} & \emph{словарная форма} \\ \hline
ます\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{нейтрально-вежливая форма; утв., наст-будущее время} \\ \hline
ない\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{простая отрицательная форма} \\ \hline
た\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{простая форма прошедшего времени} \\ \hline
て\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{срединная форма на て} \\ \hline
たり\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{репрезентативная форма глагола} \\ \hline
たら\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{условная форма на たら} \\ \hline
\ruby{条件形}{じょうけんけい}　&　\emph{условная форма} \textbf{用言、４本＋ば} \\ \hline
\ruby{意向形}{いこうけい} & \emph{форма желательного наклонения} \\ \hline
\ruby{命令形}{めいれいけい} & \emph{форма повелительное наклонения} \\ \hline
\ruby{禁止形}{きんしけい} & \emph{запретительное наклонение} \\ \hline
\ruby{可能形}{かのうけい} & \emph{форма потенциального залога} \\ \hline
\ruby{受身}{うけみ} & \emph{форма страдательного залога} \\ \hline
\ruby{使役形}{しえきけい} & \emph{форма побудительного залога} \\ \hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you thought about issuing `\clearpage\onecolumn` then your `supertabular` environment and then switching on `\twocolumn`?  Also, you should use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}\end{center}`.

Comment: It works, however, new page required. Also, the text after table will begin from next page. There will be two-columns tables smaller than represented in MWE. Therefore, I need the solution without \clearpage...

Comment: So it works without issuing clearpage?

Comment: I can never get `XeLaTeX` to work so I can't test my suggestions.  So the best I can do is offer them and here back from you.

Comment: Is the `longtable` package an option?

Comment: Ruben, longtable is not compatible with multicolumn typesetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the default `\twocolum` mode, which starts, of course, a new page but allows a columnbreak for the tabular:

```
...
\twocolumn
\rowcolors{1}{文法字引表薄い}{文法字引表濃い}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{supertabular}{|m{15mm}|m{34mm}|} \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{文法字引表見出し}\bfseries\ruby{品詞}{ひんし}・Части речи} \\ \hline\hline
\ruby{動詞}{どうし} & \emph{глагол} \\ \hline
...
\ruby{使役形}{しえきけい} & \emph{форма побудительного залога} \\ \hline
\end{supertabular}

\onecolumn
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I found myself is **paracol** package. Unfortunately, you need to close the **tabular** environment and switch the column, however, it appears like two-column **longtable**:
[image: Tabular in two columns - paracol solution]

The next code is for XeLaTeX application:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS PMincho}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.1ex}

\oddsidemargin=-10.4mm  % Margin of odd pages
\evensidemargin=-20.4mm % Margin of even pages
\topmargin=-35mm        %
\textwidth=190mm        %
\textheight=275mm       %

\parindent=5mm          %
\righthyphenmin=2


\begin{document}

\definecolor{文法字引表薄い}{rgb}{0.99,0.91,0.85}
\definecolor{文法字引表濃い}{rgb}{0.99,0.83,0.7}
\definecolor{文法字引表見出し}{rgb}{0.99,0.91,0.85}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{文法字引表薄い}{文法字引表濃い}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|m{25mm}|m{57mm}|} \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{文法字引表見出し} \bfseries\qquad \ruby{品詞}{ひんし}・Части речи} \\ \hline\hline
\ruby{動詞}{どうし} & \emph{глагол} \\ \hline
動詞I & \emph{глагол 1 группы} \\ \hline
動詞II & \emph{глагол 2 группы} \\ \hline
\ruby{自動詞}{じどうし} & \emph{непереходный глагол} \\ \hline
\ruby{他動詞}{たどうし} & \emph{переходный глагол} \\ \hline
\ruby{意思}{いし}\ruby{表示}{ひょうじ}動詞 & \emph{волевой (волеизъявительный глагол)} \\ \hline
\ruby{無}{む}意思表示動詞 & \emph{неволевой (неволеизъявительный) глагол} \\ \hline
\ruby{形容詞}{けいようし} & \emph{прилагательное} \\ \hline
い形容詞 & \emph{предикативное прилагательное} \\ \hline
な形容詞 & \emph{полупредикативное прилагательное} \\ \hline
\ruby{名詞}{めいし} & \emph{существительное} \\ \hline
\ruby{用言}{ようげん} & \emph{изменяемые части речи(動詞＋い形容詞)} \\ \hline
\ruby{体言}{たいげん} & \emph{неизменяемые части речи(名詞＋な形容詞)} \\ \hline
\ruby{副詞}{ふくし} & \emph{наречие} \\ \hline
\ruby{助詞}{じょし} & \emph{частица} \\ \hline
\ruby{接続詞}{せつぞくし} & \emph{союз} \\ \hline
\ruby{疑問視}{ぎもんし} & \emph{вопросительное слово} \\ \hline
\ruby{助数詞}{じょすうし} & \emph{счётный суффикс} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{文法字引表見出し} \bfseries\qquad \ruby{品詞}{ひんし}の\ruby{形}{けい}・Формы частей речи} \\ \hline\hline
X\ruby{本}{ほん} & \emph{функциональная основа, X=1,2,3,4,5} \\ \hline
\ruby{普通形}{ふつうけい} & \emph{простая форма} \\ \hline
\ruby{丁寧形}{ていねいけい} & \emph{нейтрально-вежливая форма} \\ \hline
\ruby{辞書形}{じしょけい} & \emph{словарная форма} \\ \hline
ます\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{нейтрально-вежливая форма; утв., наст-будущее время} \\ \hline
ない\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{простая отрицательная форма} \\ \hline
た\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{простая форма прошедшего времени} \\ \hline
て\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{срединная форма на て} \\ \hline
たり\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{репрезентативная форма глагола} \\ \hline
たら\ruby{形}{けい} & \emph{условная форма на たら} \\ \hline
\ruby{条件形}{じょうけんけい}　&　\emph{условная форма} \textbf{用言、４本＋ば} \\ \hline
\ruby{意向形}{いこうけい} & \emph{форма желательного наклонения} \\ \hline
\end{tabular} \end{center}
\switchcolumn
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{文法字引表薄い}{文法字引表濃い}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|m{25mm}|m{57mm}|} \hline
\ruby{命令形}{めいれいけい} & \emph{форма повелительное наклонения} \\ \hline
\ruby{禁止形}{きんしけい} & \emph{запретительное наклонение} \\ \hline
\ruby{可能形}{かのうけい} & \emph{форма потенциального залога} \\ \hline
\ruby{受身}{うけみ} & \emph{форма страдательного залога} \\ \hline
\ruby{使役形}{しえきけい} & \emph{форма побудительного залога} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```