# How to make a table's columns fill up the page horizontally?

Tags: tables

I would like to stretch out the content of the table/`tabular`-environment over as many columns on the first and second page as possible. How can I achieve that?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
booktabs,
longtable,
multicol
}


\begin{document}
%\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{longtable}{rr}
\toprule
Number & Letter\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
1     & A \\
2     & B \\
3     & C \\
4     & A \\
5     & B \\
6     & C \\
7     & A \\
8     & B \\
9     & C \\
10    & A \\
11    & B \\
12    & C \\
13    & A \\
14    & B \\
15    & C \\
16    & A \\
17    & B \\
18    & C \\
19    & A \\
20    & B \\
21    & C \\
22    & A \\
23    & B \\
24    & C \\
25    & A \\
26    & B \\
27    & C \\
28    & A \\
29    & B \\
30    & C \\
31    & A \\
32    & B \\
33    & C \\
34    & A \\
35    & B \\
36    & C \\
37    & A \\
38    & B \\
39    & C \\
40    & A \\
41    & B \\
42    & C \\
43    & A \\
44    & B \\
45    & C \\
46    & A \\
47    & B \\
48    & C \\
49    & A \\
50    & B \\
51    & C \\
52    & A \\
53    & B \\
54    & C \\
55    & A \\
56    & B \\
57    & C \\
58    & A \\
59    & B \\
60    & C \\
61    & A \\
62    & B \\
63    & C \\
64    & A \\
65    & B \\
66    & C \\
67    & A \\
68    & B \\
69    & C \\
70    & A \\
71    & B \\
72    & C \\
73    & A \\
74    & B \\
75    & C \\
76    & A \\
77    & B \\
78    & C \\
79    & A \\
80    & B \\
81    & C \\
82    & A \\
83    & B \\
84    & C \\
85    & A \\
86    & B \\
87    & C \\
88    & A \\
89    & B \\
90    & C \\
91    & A \\
92    & B \\
93    & C \\
94    & A \\
95    & B \\
96    & C \\
97    & A \\
98    & B \\
99    & C \\
100   & A \\
101   & B \\
102   & C \\
103   & A \\
104   & B \\
105   & C \\
106   & A \\
107   & B \\
108   & C \\
109   & A \\
110   & B \\
111   & C \\
112   & A \\
113   & B \\
114   & C \\
115   & A \\
116   & B \\
117   & C \\
118   & A \\
119   & B \\
120   & C \\
121   & A \\
122   & B \\
123   & C \\
124   & A \\
125   & B \\
126   & C \\
127   & A \\
128   & B \\
129   & C \\
130   & A \\
131   & B \\
132   & C \\
133   & A \\
134   & B \\
135   & C \\
136   & A \\
\end{longtable}
%\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**The Goal** (quickly edited in Gimp, thus very low quality)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5kNPkt5.png).

Comment: Doesn't work neither. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/BuodRdq.png). Also, putting this code bit in the preamble, doesn't this affect all `longtable`-environments?

Comment: Done. Edited the op. :) Just to make sure: I would like the other longtables to be processed normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "brute force" solution uses some code stolen from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46001/27635) of David Carlisle.

MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
booktabs,
longtable,
multicol
}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
\makeatletter\col@number\@ne
\begin{longtable}{rr}
\toprule
Number & Letter\\
\midrule
1     & A \\
2     & B \\
3     & C \\
4     & A \\
5     & B \\
6     & C \\
7     & A \\
8     & B \\
9     & C \\
10    & A \\
11    & B \\
12    & C \\
13    & A \\
14    & B \\
15    & C \\
16    & A \\
17    & B \\
18    & C \\
19    & A \\
20    & B \\
21    & C \\
22    & A \\
23    & B \\
24    & C \\
25    & A \\
26    & B \\
27    & C \\
28    & A \\
29    & B \\
30    & C \\
31    & A \\
32    & B \\
33    & C \\
34    & A \\
35    & B \\
36    & C \\
37    & A \\
38    & B \\
39    & C \\
40    & A \\
\bottomrule
\\[3pt]
\toprule
Number & Letter\\
\midrule
41    & B \\
42    & C \\
43    & A \\
44    & B \\
45    & C \\
46    & A \\
47    & B \\
48    & C \\
49    & A \\
50    & B \\
51    & C \\
52    & A \\
53    & B \\
54    & C \\
55    & A \\
56    & B \\
57    & C \\
58    & A \\
59    & B \\
60    & C \\
61    & A \\
62    & B \\
63    & C \\
64    & A \\
65    & B \\
66    & C \\
67    & A \\
68    & B \\
69    & C \\
70    & A \\
71    & B \\
72    & C \\
73    & A \\
74    & B \\
75    & C \\
76    & A \\
77    & B \\
78    & C \\
79    & A \\
80    & B \\
\bottomrule
\\[3pt]
\toprule
Number & Letter\\
\midrule
81    & C \\
82    & A \\
83    & B \\
84    & C \\
85    & A \\
86    & B \\
87    & C \\
88    & A \\
89    & B \\
90    & C \\
91    & A \\
92    & B \\
93    & C \\
94    & A \\
95    & B \\
96    & C \\
97    & A \\
98    & B \\
99    & C \\
100   & A \\
101   & B \\
102   & C \\
103   & A \\
104   & B \\
105   & C \\
106   & A \\
107   & B \\
108   & C \\
109   & A \\
110   & B \\
111   & C \\
112   & A \\
113   & B \\
114   & C \\
115   & A \\
116   & B \\
117   & C \\
118   & A \\
119   & B \\
120   & C \\
\bottomrule
\\[3pt]
\toprule
Number & Letter\\
\midrule
121   & A \\
122   & B \\
123   & C \\
124   & A \\
125   & B \\
126   & C \\
127   & A \\
128   & B \\
129   & C \\
130   & A \\
131   & B \\
132   & C \\
133   & A \\
134   & B \\
135   & C \\
136   & A \\
\bottomrule
\\[3pt]
\pagebreak
\end{longtable}
\unskip
\unpenalty
\unpenalty}

\unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Output

> [image]