# Split Very long table on one page then continue on next page part 2

Tags: supertabular

This question is building off the [solution found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361805/split-very-long-table-on-one-page-then-continue-on-next-page/362326?noredirect=1#comment896594_362326).  This solution given on that post, begins the table on the next page.  How to begin the table on the same page as the `\section` or `\chapter` beginning?

Also, from the code given below, although the data is complete, a header with no data is printed on a new page.  How to overcome this issue?

Here is the MWE:

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
                \usepackage{supertabular}
                \usepackage{amsmath}
                \usepackage{array}
                \usepackage{fancyhdr}
                \pagestyle{fancy}
                \fancyhf{}

                \usepackage{filecontents}
                \begin{filecontents}{verylong.txt}
                c   G(c)GTOT    GhatGTOT    MODELPERFORM
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.893617021 0.629976581 0.585480094 0.92936803
                0.888297872 0.644028103 0.592505855 0.92
                0.882978723 0.658079625 0.613583138 0.932384342
                0.877659574 0.672131148 0.62295082  0.926829268
                0.872340426 0.683840749 0.634660422 0.928082192
                0.867021277 0.695550351 0.641686183 0.922558923
                0.861702128 0.707259953 0.641686183 0.907284768
                0.856382979 0.718969555 0.644028103 0.895765472
                0.85106383  0.730679157 0.655737705 0.897435897
                0.845744681 0.742388759 0.669789227 0.902208202
                0.840425532 0.754098361 0.669789227 0.888198758
                0.835106383 0.763466042 0.669789227 0.877300613
                0.829787234 0.772833724 0.683840749 0.884848485
                0.824468085 0.782201405 0.68852459  0.880239521
                0.819148936 0.791569087 0.700234192 0.884615385
                0.813829787 0.800936768 0.711943794 0.888888889
                0.808510638 0.81030445  0.716627635 0.884393064
                0.803191489 0.817330211 0.723653396 0.885386819
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.638297872 0.948477752 0.880562061 0.928395062
                0.632978723 0.950819672 0.880562061 0.926108374
                0.627659574 0.953161593 0.880562061 0.923832924
                0.622340426 0.955503513 0.880562061 0.921568627
                0.617021277 0.957845433 0.880562061 0.919315403
                0.611702128 0.960187354 0.880562061 0.917073171
                0.606382979 0.962529274 0.880562061 0.914841849
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.521276596 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.515957447 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.510638298 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.505319149 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.5 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.494680851 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
                0.489361702 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
                0.484042553 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.478723404 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.473404255 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.468085106 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.462765957 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
                0.457446809 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
                0.45212766  1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.446808511 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.441489362 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.436170213 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.367021277 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
                0.361702128 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
                0.356382979 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.35106383  1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.345744681 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.340425532 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.335106383 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.329787234 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.324468085 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.319148936 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.313829787 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                \end{filecontents}


                \begin{document}
                \section{This is a VERY LONG TABLE}
                \twocolumn

                %%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
                \pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
                    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
                    \pgfplotstableset{
                        empty header/.style={
                          every head row/.style={output empty row},
                          outfile=pgfplotstable.example1.out.tex,
                        }
                    }
                }{
                    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
                    \pgfplotstableset{
                        empty header/.style={
                            typeset cell/.append code={%
                                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                                \fi
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                \noindent
                {\scriptsize
                % define tab first header
                \tablefirsthead{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule\\}
                %define subsequent headers
                \tablehead{\multicolumn{8}{c}%
                    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ \textit{(Continued)}}}\\
                    \toprule
                    %
                    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule\\}
                %define tails
                \tabletail{ \midrule \multicolumn{8}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \bottomrule\\}
                %define last tail
                \tablelasttail{\midrule\multicolumn{8}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule\\}
                %define caption
                \tablecaption{This is a Table with Data}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
                columns={c,G(c)GTOT,GhatGTOT,MODELPERFORM},      % display specified columns
                begin table=\begin{supertabular},
                end table=\end{supertabular},
                columns/c/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                columns/G(c)GTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                columns/GhatGTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                columns/MODELPERFORM/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                every head row/.append style={before row={%
                    \label{tab:DataTable}
                    }},
                ]{verylong.txt}
                \onecolumn %restores one-column output
                \end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not compile…

Comment: I was able to get it to compile on my machine...I checked it by copying and pasting the code into my compiler and it compiles.  What error do you get?  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, had to clean aux files :) works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230646/89949), I suggest you introduce the following command:

```
\makeatletter
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{%
\renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn%
        \hrule width\linewidth height0pt%
            \columnbreak%
        \else%
          \mcnewpage%
        \fi%
}%
}
\makeatother
```

which basically tricks `supertabular` into breaking into a new column instead of a new page while in the `multicols(*)` environment

So this is the solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
                \usepackage{supertabular}
                \makeatletter
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{%
\renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn%
        \hrule width\linewidth height0pt%
            \columnbreak%
        \else%
          \mcnewpage%
        \fi%
}%
}
\makeatother



       \usepackage{amsmath}
            \usepackage{array}
            \usepackage{fancyhdr}
            \pagestyle{fancy}
            \fancyhf{}

            \usepackage{filecontents}
            \begin{filecontents}{verylong.txt}
            c   G(c)GTOT    GhatGTOT    MODELPERFORM
            0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
            0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
            0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.015957447 1   1   1
            0.010638298 1   1   1
            0.005319149 1   1   1
            0   1   1   1
            0.893617021 0.629976581 0.585480094 0.92936803
            0.888297872 0.644028103 0.592505855 0.92
            0.882978723 0.658079625 0.613583138 0.932384342
            0.877659574 0.672131148 0.62295082  0.926829268
            0.872340426 0.683840749 0.634660422 0.928082192
            0.867021277 0.695550351 0.641686183 0.922558923
            0.861702128 0.707259953 0.641686183 0.907284768
            0.856382979 0.718969555 0.644028103 0.895765472
            0.85106383  0.730679157 0.655737705 0.897435897
            0.845744681 0.742388759 0.669789227 0.902208202
            0.840425532 0.754098361 0.669789227 0.888198758
            0.835106383 0.763466042 0.669789227 0.877300613
            0.829787234 0.772833724 0.683840749 0.884848485
            0.824468085 0.782201405 0.68852459  0.880239521
            0.819148936 0.791569087 0.700234192 0.884615385
            0.813829787 0.800936768 0.711943794 0.888888889
            0.808510638 0.81030445  0.716627635 0.884393064
            0.803191489 0.817330211 0.723653396 0.885386819
            0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
            0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
            0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.015957447 1   1   1
            0.010638298 1   1   1
            0.005319149 1   1   1
            0   1   1   1
            0.638297872 0.948477752 0.880562061 0.928395062
            0.632978723 0.950819672 0.880562061 0.926108374
            0.627659574 0.953161593 0.880562061 0.923832924
            0.622340426 0.955503513 0.880562061 0.921568627
            0.617021277 0.957845433 0.880562061 0.919315403
            0.611702128 0.960187354 0.880562061 0.917073171
            0.606382979 0.962529274 0.880562061 0.914841849
            0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
            0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
            0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.015957447 1   1   1
            0.010638298 1   1   1
            0.005319149 1   1   1
            0   1   1   1
            0.521276596 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
            0.515957447 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
            0.510638298 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
            0.505319149 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
            0.5 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
            0.494680851 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
            0.489361702 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
            0.484042553 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
            0.478723404 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
            0.473404255 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
            0.468085106 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
            0.462765957 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
            0.457446809 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
            0.45212766  1   0.925058548 0.925058548
            0.446808511 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
            0.441489362 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
            0.436170213 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
            0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
            0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
            0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
            0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
            0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
            0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
            0.015957447 1   1   1
            0.010638298 1   1   1
            0.005319149 1   1   1
            0   1   1   1
            0.367021277 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
            0.361702128 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
            0.356382979 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.35106383  1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.345744681 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.340425532 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.335106383 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.329787234 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.324468085 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.319148936 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.313829787 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
            0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
            0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
            \end{filecontents}


            \begin{document}

            \section{This is a VERY LONG TABLE}
            \begin{multicols*}{2}
            \TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols
            %%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
            \pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
                % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
                \pgfplotstableset{
                    empty header/.style={
                      every head row/.style={output empty row},
                      outfile=pgfplotstable.example1.out.tex,
                    }
                }
            }{
                % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
                \pgfplotstableset{
                    empty header/.style={
                        typeset cell/.append code={%
                            \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                            \fi
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            \noindent
            {\scriptsize
            % define tab first header
            \tablefirsthead{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule\\}
            %define subsequent headers
            \tablehead{\multicolumn{8}{c}%
                {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ \textit{(Continued)}}}\\
                \toprule
                %
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule\\}
            %define tails
            \tabletail{ \midrule \multicolumn{8}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \bottomrule\\}
            %define last tail
            \tablelasttail{\midrule\multicolumn{8}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule\\}}
            %define caption
            \tablecaption{This is a Table with Data}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
            columns={c,G(c)GTOT,GhatGTOT,MODELPERFORM},      % display specified columns
            begin table=\begin{supertabular},
            end table=\end{supertabular},
            columns/c/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
            columns/G(c)GTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
            columns/GhatGTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
            columns/MODELPERFORM/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
            every head row/.append style={before row={%
                \label{tab:DataTable}
                }},
            ]{verylong.txt}

            \end{multicols*} %restores one-column output

            test
            \end{document}
```

Yielding:

[image]

---

**DETAILS**

- In your preamble include the code about `\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols` and also `\usepackage{multicol}`
- Get rid of `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn`
- Use `\begin{multicols*}{2}` (assuming you want two columns) before the table. This starred version simply does not want to obtain perfectly balanced columns in the last page (I would recommend to keep the starred version)
- Immediately below that use `\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols`
- Put there the code (i.e. from `\pgfkeysifdefined` on)
- At the end of the table put `\end{multicols*}`