# clash of tabularx and conditions

Tags: tabularx, ltablex

page table coming from a csv file.
My problem: there is an error arrising in the condition before the table. 
Do you know how I can fix this problem? (Not all the data is shown but it is important that the table stays multi-page like.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
  \keepXColumns
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{float}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
%________________________________________________________________________
\newenvironment{conditions}
{\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X}}
{\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
%________________________________________________________________________
% Part 4
\begin{filecontents*}{exp4.csv}
0.2,320.1
0.4,319.5
0.6,317.7
\end{filecontents*}
%________________________________________________________________________
\begin{document}
%________________________________________________________________________

\begin{conditions} 
\kappa & specific conductivity [$\si{\siemens~\cm^{-1}}$]  \\
 \end{conditions}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \bfseries V EDTA [\si{\milli\liter}] & \bfseries value 1 
    \csvreader[no head]{exp4.csv}{}{\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcolii }
    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently you use `ltablex` to make `tabularx` tables be able to occupy multiple pages (This is not the standard behaviour of `tabularx`.) `ltablex` seems to cause the issue here. Would you mind switching to an alternative package such as `xltabular` instead?

Comment: Is there a special reason for using `tabularx` for this kind of table in the first place? You introduce a huge amount of white space in the table making it less visually appealing and harder to read. Why not use two `l` type columns and a regular `longtable` instead?

Comment: could you give me an example? that would be very helful :) the reason why i used tabularx was that I can split the chart on two pages because there are to many rows for having the table only on one page but if you have a better solution that would be great

Comment: The `tabularx` package does not allow you to make tables span multiple pages. It only allows you to use `X` type columns and specify an overall width for the table. If you want tables that can span multiple pages, use `longtable`. If you want to combine the features of `tabularx`(`X` type columns)  and `longtable`(pagebreaks) in one table, there are multiple packages. One of them is `ltablex` that you used and that also causes the error message here. An alternative to that is the `xltabular` package that I used in my answer.

Comment: Your table currently only contains two columns with wuite narrow contents in each. With your use of `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` you made the actually quite narrow table as wide as the textwidth introducing a lot of unused white space in both columns. For such a table with few columns and narrow contents in each columns, there is no need for `X` type columns (and `tabularx`or `xltabular` at all). You can just use a regular `longtable` instead as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples using either `xltabular` or `longtable`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{ltablex} % removed to get rid of error message
%  \keepXColumns
\usepackage{xltabular} % added to be able to use xltabular environment. with this package, use tabularx if you don't want a pagebreak, use xltabular of you do want a pagebreak inside of a table.
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{float}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
%________________________________________________________________________
\newenvironment{conditions}
{\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X}}
{\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
%________________________________________________________________________
% Part 4
\begin{filecontents*}{exp4.csv}
0.2,320.1
0.4,319.5
0.6,317.7
\end{filecontents*}
%________________________________________________________________________
\begin{document}
%________________________________________________________________________

\begin{conditions} 
\kappa & specific conductivity [$\si{\siemens~\cm^{-1}}$]  \\
\end{conditions}

xltabular version

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \bfseries V EDTA [\si{\milli\liter}] & \bfseries value 1 
    \csvreader[no head]{exp4.csv}{}{\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcolii }
    \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

longtable version

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \bfseries V EDTA [\si{\milli\liter}] & \bfseries value 1 
    \csvreader[no head]{exp4.csv}{}{\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcolii }
    \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. That helps me a lot to understand how to use the different type of charts. I was not very familiar with this.

Comment: Could I also use \usepackage{multicol} with this in order two have 2 colums on just one page? (\begin{multicols}{2} and \end{multicols})

Comment: No, `longtable` does only work in onecolumn mode. However, here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230652/134144 is way to make it work nevertheless.