# How to use three columns for table?

Tags: tables, columns

I am aware of using supertabular and the \twocolumn environment for tables over two columns. But is also possible to use a three column layout with a long table?

Comment: this would work for three or more columns, with the same restrictions as stated in tthe answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46001/1090