# Howto break columns in mcexam and longtables

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, longtable, multicol, mcexam

Friends!

I want to typeset a mcexam (or longtable) in a multicol framework.

Is it possible to break columns more properly, i.e. with some variant of `\columnbreak`?

The only workaround I found is using a spacing argument, as the `\vspace{.1pt}` in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[output=exam,randomizequestions=false]{mcexam}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setbox\mybox\vbox{
\makeatletter\col@number\@ne
\begin{mcquestions}
\question How much is $2+2$?\par
\begin{mcanswerslist}
\answer two
\answer[correct] four
\answer five
\answer six
\answer seven
\answer eight
\end{mcanswerslist}
\vspace{.1pt}
\question How much is $5-3$?
\begin{mcanswerslist}
\answer 1
\answer[correct] 2
\end{mcanswerslist}
\end{mcquestions}
\unskip
\unpenalty
\unpenalty}
\unvbox\mybox
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

that yields

[image: pdfLaTeX output]

Without the spacing argument `\vspace{.1pt}` Tex generates a Hurenkind like this,

[image: pdfLaTeX output without spacing argument]

which is ugly and confusing: Imagin the last answer of a multiple choice question is on the next page.

My question is a followup to [Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex), making havy use of David Carlisle's answer.

PS

This is my first question on tex.stackexchange, even if I'm working with TeX and friends since 1990.