# tabularray (longtblr) to

Tags: multicol, tabularray

I need to create a document with frequently changing between one and two columns and a lot of (long)tables and sometimes including a (multipage) pdf document.
The complete document and resulting pdf is created automatically, so no possibility to inject column or page breaks manually.

I choose tabularray for it's wide and easy possibilites of  row- and col-spanning as well as creating long tables.

I started with multicols package, but chapters with too many long tables have problems in correct column/page breaks.

...finally I found this post [Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex/46001#46001)

Any chance that this works with tabularray as well?

This is what it tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox

\def\shortlipsum{\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\par}

\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}
\def\tabline{Test & \the\value{entryno} & Description\addtocounter{entryno}{1}\\}
\def\tablines{\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline\tabline}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \shortlipsum
        \medskip
        
        \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
            \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
            \begin{longtblr}[caption={}, label=none, entry=none]{colspec={lll}}
                %\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines\tablines
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
                a & b & c\\
            \end{longtblr}
            \unskip
            \unpenalty
            \unpenalty}
        
        \unvbox\ltmcbox
        
        
        \medskip
        \shortlipsum
    \end{multicols}
    \shortlipsum
\end{document}
```

Sorry for my ugly code, but I didn't get the tablines macros working inside the table.

[image]

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I already tried it. I think that the trick `\makeatletter\col@number\@ne` is not working for longtblr, but I don't know which variable would be the equivalent, or I'm on the wrong track...

Comment: well if you provided an example and showed  what error you get someone might run it and debug. without that unlikely unless the tabularray author passes by (which he does quite often)

Comment: I have tried this before, but the problem is that `longtblr` puts the rows into several layers of boxes. `longtable` on the other hand puts it into a single box, which is removed by `\unvbox\ltmcbox`. It doesn't help to unbox the `longtblr` several times because there are also other elements (like penalties or spaces or so, if I remember correctly) that makes it impossible to break the thing apart in standard LaTeX. Maybe some Lua code in Luatex could do it?