# how puts a long table in two columns

Tags: lyx, longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex)

In a document without columns, how puts only a long table in a two columns to save space ?

Others possible duplicate answers related use of package like supertabular, this involve re-write the table. Also this is possible in lyx ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I am not fully understanding the question. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages. Basically shows us what you are doing as opposed to describing it. Lyx is just an editor so yes it should be doable in Lyx.

Comment: If you mean the package `longtable`, I don't think it can be used in two-column mode.  (Or do you mean a table that is long?)

Comment: Please show the existing "long table" and what the desired output should look like.

Comment: Maybe this question for a [multicolumn long table or enumeration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13895/17198) is suitable for your problem as well?!