# Split Very long table on one page then continue on next page

Tags: longtable, multicol

I wanted to split a narrow, very long table, on one page, then after that page is full, continue the table on the page.

I looked at the solutions posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134381/dealing-with-very-long-table-split-into-columns) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103457/continue-long-table-beside-on-the-same-page), but could not get a proper output.  I am pulling the data generated from measurements that is saved to a text file, hence the `filecontents`.

Please help me (if possible) to get the table on multiple columns on one page then continue on the next page.

Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{verylong.txt}
c   G(c)GTOT    GhatGTOT    MODELPERFORM
0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.015957447 1   1   1
0.010638298 1   1   1
0.005319149 1   1   1
0   1   1   1
0.893617021 0.629976581 0.585480094 0.92936803
0.888297872 0.644028103 0.592505855 0.92
0.882978723 0.658079625 0.613583138 0.932384342
0.877659574 0.672131148 0.62295082  0.926829268
0.872340426 0.683840749 0.634660422 0.928082192
0.867021277 0.695550351 0.641686183 0.922558923
0.861702128 0.707259953 0.641686183 0.907284768
0.856382979 0.718969555 0.644028103 0.895765472
0.85106383  0.730679157 0.655737705 0.897435897
0.845744681 0.742388759 0.669789227 0.902208202
0.840425532 0.754098361 0.669789227 0.888198758
0.835106383 0.763466042 0.669789227 0.877300613
0.829787234 0.772833724 0.683840749 0.884848485
0.824468085 0.782201405 0.68852459  0.880239521
0.819148936 0.791569087 0.700234192 0.884615385
0.813829787 0.800936768 0.711943794 0.888888889
0.808510638 0.81030445  0.716627635 0.884393064
0.803191489 0.817330211 0.723653396 0.885386819
0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.015957447 1   1   1
0.010638298 1   1   1
0.005319149 1   1   1
0   1   1   1
0.638297872 0.948477752 0.880562061 0.928395062
0.632978723 0.950819672 0.880562061 0.926108374
0.627659574 0.953161593 0.880562061 0.923832924
0.622340426 0.955503513 0.880562061 0.921568627
0.617021277 0.957845433 0.880562061 0.919315403
0.611702128 0.960187354 0.880562061 0.917073171
0.606382979 0.962529274 0.880562061 0.914841849
0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.015957447 1   1   1
0.010638298 1   1   1
0.005319149 1   1   1
0   1   1   1
0.521276596 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
0.515957447 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
0.510638298 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
0.505319149 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
0.5 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
0.494680851 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
0.489361702 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
0.484042553 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
0.478723404 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
0.473404255 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
0.468085106 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
0.462765957 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
0.457446809 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
0.45212766  1   0.925058548 0.925058548
0.446808511 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
0.441489362 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
0.436170213 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.015957447 1   1   1
0.010638298 1   1   1
0.005319149 1   1   1
0   1   1   1
0.367021277 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
0.361702128 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
0.356382979 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.35106383  1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.345744681 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.340425532 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.335106383 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.329787234 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.324468085 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.319148936 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.313829787 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.015957447 1   1   1
0.010638298 1   1   1
0.005319149 1   1   1
0   1   1   1
0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.015957447 1   1   1
0.010638298 1   1   1
0.005319149 1   1   1
0   1   1   1
0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
0.015957447 1   1   1
0.010638298 1   1   1
0.005319149 1   1   1
0   1   1   1
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}


%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
          outfile=pgfplotstable.example1.out.tex,
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\noindent
{\scriptsize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
columns={c,G(c)GTOT,GhatGTOT,MODELPERFORM},      % display specified columns
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
columns/c/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/G(c)GTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/GhatGTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/MODELPERFORM/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{This is a Table with Data}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{8}{c}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ \textit{(Continued)}}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{8}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{8}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},
]{verylong.txt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should switch to `supertabular` instead of `longtable`.

The package should do what you need.

Here the code

```
                \documentclass{book}
                \usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
                \usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
                \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
                \usepackage{supertabular}
                \usepackage{amsmath}
                \usepackage{array}
                \usepackage{fancyhdr}
                \pagestyle{fancy}
                \fancyhf{}

                \usepackage{filecontents}
                \begin{filecontents}{verylong.txt}
                c   G(c)GTOT    GhatGTOT    MODELPERFORM
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.893617021 0.629976581 0.585480094 0.92936803
                0.888297872 0.644028103 0.592505855 0.92
                0.882978723 0.658079625 0.613583138 0.932384342
                0.877659574 0.672131148 0.62295082  0.926829268
                0.872340426 0.683840749 0.634660422 0.928082192
                0.867021277 0.695550351 0.641686183 0.922558923
                0.861702128 0.707259953 0.641686183 0.907284768
                0.856382979 0.718969555 0.644028103 0.895765472
                0.85106383  0.730679157 0.655737705 0.897435897
                0.845744681 0.742388759 0.669789227 0.902208202
                0.840425532 0.754098361 0.669789227 0.888198758
                0.835106383 0.763466042 0.669789227 0.877300613
                0.829787234 0.772833724 0.683840749 0.884848485
                0.824468085 0.782201405 0.68852459  0.880239521
                0.819148936 0.791569087 0.700234192 0.884615385
                0.813829787 0.800936768 0.711943794 0.888888889
                0.808510638 0.81030445  0.716627635 0.884393064
                0.803191489 0.817330211 0.723653396 0.885386819
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.638297872 0.948477752 0.880562061 0.928395062
                0.632978723 0.950819672 0.880562061 0.926108374
                0.627659574 0.953161593 0.880562061 0.923832924
                0.622340426 0.955503513 0.880562061 0.921568627
                0.617021277 0.957845433 0.880562061 0.919315403
                0.611702128 0.960187354 0.880562061 0.917073171
                0.606382979 0.962529274 0.880562061 0.914841849
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.521276596 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.515957447 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.510638298 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.505319149 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.5 1   0.915690867 0.915690867
                0.494680851 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
                0.489361702 1   0.918032787 0.918032787
                0.484042553 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.478723404 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.473404255 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.468085106 1   0.920374707 0.920374707
                0.462765957 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
                0.457446809 1   0.922716628 0.922716628
                0.45212766  1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.446808511 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.441489362 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.436170213 1   0.925058548 0.925058548
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.367021277 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
                0.361702128 1   0.948477752 0.948477752
                0.356382979 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.35106383  1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.345744681 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.340425532 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.335106383 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.329787234 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.324468085 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.319148936 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.313829787 1   0.950819672 0.950819672
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                0.10106383  1   0.971896956 0.971896956
                0.095744681 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.090425532 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.085106383 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.079787234 1   0.974238876 0.974238876
                0.074468085 1   0.976580796 0.976580796
                0.069148936 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.063829787 1   0.978922717 0.978922717
                0.058510638 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.053191489 1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.04787234  1   0.981264637 0.981264637
                0.042553191 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.037234043 1   0.990632319 0.990632319
                0.031914894 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.026595745 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.021276596 1   0.992974239 0.992974239
                0.015957447 1   1   1
                0.010638298 1   1   1
                0.005319149 1   1   1
                0   1   1   1
                \end{filecontents}


                \begin{document}
                \twocolumn

                %%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
                \pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
                    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
                    \pgfplotstableset{
                        empty header/.style={
                          every head row/.style={output empty row},
                          outfile=pgfplotstable.example1.out.tex,
                        }
                    }
                }{
                    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
                    \pgfplotstableset{
                        empty header/.style={
                            typeset cell/.append code={%
                                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                                \fi
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                \noindent
                {\scriptsize
                % define tab first header
                \tablefirsthead{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule\\}
                %define subsequent headers
                \tablehead{\multicolumn{8}{c}%
                    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ \textit{(Continued)}}}\\
                    \toprule
                    %
                    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{G(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\dfrac{\hat{G}(c)}{G_{TOT}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi(c)$} \\[7pt] \toprule\\}
                %define tails
                \tabletail{ \midrule \multicolumn{8}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \bottomrule\\}
                %define last tail
                \tablelasttail{\midrule\multicolumn{8}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule\\}
                %define caption
                \tablecaption{This is a Table with Data}
                \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
                columns={c,G(c)GTOT,GhatGTOT,MODELPERFORM},      % display specified columns
                begin table=\begin{supertabular},
                end table=\end{supertabular},
                columns/c/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                columns/G(c)GTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                columns/GhatGTOT/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                columns/MODELPERFORM/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
                every head row/.append style={before row={%
                    \label{tab:DataTable}
                    }},
                ]{verylong.txt}
                \onecolumn %restores one-column output
                \end{document}
```

Here is the output I get, page 1:

[image]

and page 2:

[image]

**The key points**

- Substitute `\usepackage{longtable}` with `\usepackage{supertabular}`
- Provide the command `\twocolumn` in your document, to enable two-column composition
- Before the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` you should use:

  - `\tablefirsthead` to define the first header of the table.
  - `\tablehead` to define the other headers
  - `\tabletail` to define the footer of your table (not the last one)
  - `\tablelasttail` to define the last footer
  - `\tablecaption` to provide the table caption.
- Remember to switch back to one-column composition by providing `\onecolumn` at the end of the table.

All of this is documented in `supertabular`documentation

Comment: thanks for your inputs, but how do you get back out of the `\twocolumn` mode?  My main body of my document is the single column.

Comment: @Joe you should provide `\onecolumn` after the table. this will start a new page with one single column

Comment: @Joe I updated my answer including that remark

Comment: Works great, but takes half an eon to compile, do you know what I could do to speed it up so I can keep it in my document, which I compile often?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the code of Dr. Christian?