# Wrong placements using xtabular for large table in twocolumn environment

Tags: tables, positioning, longtable, supertabular, xtab

I've been trying to make a large table that automatically breaks across pages and columns similar to what's described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/multicolumn-long-table-or-enumeration/14819#14819).

However, as you can see in the images, table breaks way too soon and the caption is placed awkwardly with away from the top. Here's my MWE (you can compile on overleaf [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ysfgtdnffrzx)):

```
\documentclass[journal=nalefd,manuscript=letter]{achemso}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption, multicol}

\makeatletter
\let\mcnewpage\newpage
\newcommand{\changenewpage}{%
  \renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
      \hrule width\columnwidth height0pt
      \columnbreak
    \else
      \mcnewpage
    \fi
}}
\makeatother
\title{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\changenewpage

\tablehead{
\toprule
Symbol&Description&Unit&hi\\
\midrule
}
\tabletail{\midrule}
\tablelasttail{\bottomrule}
\topcaption{Caption}

\begin{xtabular}{*{4}{c}}
\centering
\input{data.txt}

\end{xtabular}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please make your example code compilable. Since the contents of the file `data.txt` are not available to others, the ouput you show can not be reproduced.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for letting me know. Fixed it.